# String method startsWith(String) is case-sensitive or not?

Tags: string

When i tried to run the following code snippet anonymously in dev console i got different boolean results. Is string method startsWith(String) case-sensitive or not?

```
String s1 = 'Thomas Inc';
System.debug(s1.startswith('ThoMas'));
```

It returns false when i changed some letters to upper case. Do i have to convert the source and the comparison string to any of the cases before comparing? Do we have case-insensitive version of this method? Please advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [String.startsWith](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_startsWith) method **is case sensitive**.

However there is a [String.startsWithIgnoreCase](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_startsWithIgnoreCase) method which as the name notes is **case insensitive**.

Comment: Hmmmm didn't realize this.  I googled salesforce string methods.  Came to the page and it has a lot less... http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: @dphil those are the docs for database.com's release, which was APIv25. I don't know why that's the top result for apex docs but it's a pretty old copy of them at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is doing something like:

```
String s1 = 'Thomas Inc';
System.debug(s1.toUpperCase().startswith('THOMAS'));
```